# What are the top 5 lowest scoring super bowls?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, super-bowl

The New England Patriots beat the Los Angeles Rams 13 - 3 in Super Bowl LIII in the lowest scoring super bowl of all time.

What are the top 5 lease scoring super bowls ever? Please list the teams playing as well as the final score

Comment: Moderator note: this question (and the more general issue of trivia questions) is [being discussed on meta](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/909/what-is-the-consensus-on-do-it-for-me-questions). Please contribute there rather than via comments on this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Top 5 of lowest scores in a Super Bowl:

1. [Super Bowl LIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_LIII): New England Patriots - Los Angeles Rams 13-3 (16)
2. [Super Bowl VII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_VII): Miami Dolphins - Washington Redskins 14-7 (21)
3. [Super Bowl IX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_IX): Pittsburgh Steelers - Minnesota Vikings 16-6 (22)
4. [Super Bowl III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_III): New York Jets - Baltimore Colts 16-7 (23)
5. [Super Bowl VI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_VI): Dallas Cowboys - Miami Dolphins 24-3 (27)

The Rams are also tied with the Dolphins (SB VI) for the lowest scoring team in a Super Bowl with just 3 points.

[Here](http://www.espn.com/nfl/superbowl/history/winners) is a list of all previous Super Bowl results.